# How to pipe Howler.masterGain output to mediaRecorder

Tags: web-audio-api, howler.js, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to record composed Web-Audio-API output from Howler (a bunch of sounds and audio sprites combined programmatically).

So far I've tried connecting the `Howler.masterGain` context to a `createMediaStreamDestination` Node but the `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable` event only fires once and without data.

Here's an example with a wired up version here: https://jsfiddle.net/chadananda/kvzrsx5t/86/

```js
const audioURL = 'https://cdn.glitch.com/02dcea11-9bd2-4462-ac38-eeb6a5ad9530%2F331_full_beautiful-minds_0171_preview.mp3?1522829295082'

// connect MediaStreamDestination to Howler.masterGain
Howler.mute(false) // to initialize Howler internals  
let mediaDest = Howler.ctx.createMediaStreamDestination()
// first disconnect
Howler.masterGain.disconnect() 
// then reconnect to our new destination?
Howler.masterGain.connect(mediaDest)  


// set up media recorder to record output
let audioChunks = []
let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaDest.stream, {mimeType: 'audio/webm'})
mediaRecorder.onstart = (event) => { console.log('Started recording Howl output...') }
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => { if (e.data.size) audioChunks.push(e.data) }
mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
  console.log('Completed Recording', audioChunks) // why is this returning empty?
    // let buffer = new Blob(chunks)  
    // let audioPlayer = document.createElement("AUDIO")
    // audioPlayer.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(buffer)
    // audioPlayer.play()
}

// example of recording one sound looping for 3 seconds
let sound = new Howl({ html5: false, src: audioURL })
// start sound and recording
sound.play(); mediaRecorder.start()  
// stop in a few seconds 
setTimeout( ()=>{ mediaRecorder.stop(); sound.stop() }, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The recording seems to be blocked by the autoplay policy which prevents you from playing anything without a user interaction. If you trigger the recording from within a click handler it works. I created an updated version of your fiddle which does that.

https://jsfiddle.net/786zkLcu/

I only changed the last lines. The code now generates a dynamic button and attaches a click handler. This also means that the user has to click the button to start the recording.

```
const $button = document.createElement('button');

$button.innerHTML = 'click';
$button.onclick = () => {
    sound.play();
    mediaRecorder.start();

    setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        sound.stop();
    }, 5000);
};

document.body.append($button);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Howler.masterGain` changes after you create your `Howl` instance:

```js
const audioURL = 'https://cdn.glitch.com/02dcea11-9bd2-4462-ac38-eeb6a5ad9530%2F331_full_beautiful-minds_0171_preview.mp3?1522829295082';
const masterGain = Howler.masterGain;
const sound = new Howl({ html5: false, src: audioURL });
sound.play();

console.log( masterGain === Howler.masterGain ); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.3/howler.min.js"></script>
```

So the one you connect to your MediaStreamDestination node is not the one where the audio data will be passed, and hence it records only silence.

I don't realy know this library, so I can't tell why it behaves like that, or if there is a way to make it behave differently, but a simple workaround is to initialize your stream and create your recorder only after you initialized your Howl instance:

```js
onclick = e => { onclick = null; msg.remove();

const audioURL = 'https://cdn.glitch.com/02dcea11-9bd2-4462-ac38-eeb6a5ad9530%2F331_full_beautiful-minds_0171_preview.mp3?1522829295082'

Howler.mute(false) // to initialize Howler internals  

// first initiate your Howl instance
const sound = new Howl( { html5: false, src: audioURL } );
sound.play();
// now intitiate your MediaStreamDestination

const mediaDest = Howler.ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
Howler.masterGain.connect( mediaDest );

// set up media recorder to record output
const audioChunks = []
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder( mediaDest.stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' } );

mediaRecorder.onstart = (event) =>
  { console.log('Started recording Howl output...') };
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) =>
  { audioChunks.push( event.data ) };
mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) =>
  { console.log('Completed Recording', new Blob( audioChunks ) ) };

mediaRecorder.start();

setTimeout( ()=>{ mediaRecorder.stop(); sound.stop() }, 5000);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.3/howler.min.js"></script>
<pre id="msg">click anywhere to start</pre>
```